# Android WebView fit content to screen

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying to fit webview content with screen but it display very ugly and show different results, please see below link for screen capture :

http://postimg.org/image/jy0g268p1/0294ca52/

http://postimg.org/image/603z8qhab/e06b655e/

Please find below my code :

```
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setMinimumFontSize(30);
    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    settings.setSupportZoom(true); 

    webView.loadData(htmlContent,  "text/html", "UTF-8");
    webView.setInitialScale(1);
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Kindly advise what should I do to fit content nicely?
Really appreciate for any kind help.

Comment: ur content need to be formatted

Comment: You nees to specify layout parmas as "fill_parent","fill_parent" to acheive the same.

Comment: @DIVA what you mean that my content need to be formatted?

Comment: @Techfist yes I have put in my layout match_parent both for width and height

Comment: @VierdaMilaNartila u nned to make ur html page responsive

Comment: @DIVA you mean I have to put some meta tags like describe in this tutorial? http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html with value of user-scalable=yes ??

Comment: look for reponsive web design in google or u can use zoom feature in webview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
I have create my own method with set background color and font color also.

 WebSettings settings = desc.getSettings();
            settings.setMinimumFontSize(50);
            desc.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
            settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            settings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);

            desc.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
            String changeFontHtml = changedHeaderHtml(description);
            desc.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.all_app_bg_color));
            desc.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, changeFontHtml,"text/html", "UTF-8", null);
            desc.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.loadUrl("javascript:document.body.style.setProperty(\"color\", \"white\");"
                    );
                }
            });


    public static String changedHeaderHtml(String htmlText) {

            String head = "<head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, user-scalable=yes\" /></head>";

            String closedTag = "</body></html>";
            String changeFontHtml = head + htmlText + closedTag;
            return changeFontHtml;
        }
```

Answer (score 17):

This worked for me:

```
webview.Settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true;
webview.Settings.UseWideViewPort = true;
```

Answer (score 15):

I think I have found my own solution, I put here for someone who need it in future.
I just create one method to change head of html :

```
public static String changedHeaderHtml(String htmlText) {

        String head = "<head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, user-scalable=yes\" /></head>";

        String closedTag = "</body></html>";
        String changeFontHtml = head + htmlText + closedTag;
        return changeFontHtml;
    }
```

And I'm using it inside webview as follow :

```
public static void displayHtmlText(String htmlContent, String message,
        WebView webView,
        RelativeLayout videoLayout, LinearLayout standardLayout, LinearLayout webviewLayout){

    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setMinimumFontSize(18);
    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    settings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    String changeFontHtml = Util.changedHeaderHtml(htmlContent);
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, changeFontHtml,
            "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

    webviewLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    standardLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    videoLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

So my content in webview now is fit to device and can show nicely.

Comment: This solution is a bit of a hack... but is the only one that really works for me, more precisely, the html part. Html head part could be more carefully 'injected' into existing html.